# Azure DevOps - Slack integration does not work for Build completed event

Tags: azure-devops, integration, slack

I'd like to set up a connection `Azure DevOps` and `Slack`, so it'd post a message after certain events (build completed, pull request created, etc). I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/slack?view=vsts) guide, it works mostly well, however I can't make it work for the "Build completed" event. I use the same settings as for other events, but messages simply don't show up.

When using the "Test", I receive the following response

> **Error Message**
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> **Error Details**
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>    Parameter name: source
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Consumers.Slack.PostMessageToChannelAction.BuildAttachmentForBuildComplete(JObject resource) in d:\v2.0\P1_work\8\s\ServiceHooks\Sdk\Consumers\Slack\PostMessageToChannelAction.cs:line 326
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Consumers.Slack.PostMessageToChannelAction.TransformEvent(Event raisedEvent, HandleEventArgs e) in d:\v2.0\P1_work\8\s\ServiceHooks\Sdk\Consumers\Slack\PostMessageToChannelAction.cs:line 288
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Consumers.Slack.PostMessageToChannelAction.HandleEvent(IVssRequestContext requestContext, Event raisedEvent, HandleEventArgs e) in d:\v2.0\P1_work\8\s\ServiceHooks\Sdk\Consumers\Slack\PostMessageToChannelAction.cs:line 249 
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.ServiceHooksConsumerService.GetConsumerActionTaskForNotification(IVssRequestContext requestContext, Notification notification) in d:\v2.0\P1_work\8\s\ServiceHooks\Sdk\Server\Consumers\ServiceHooksConsumerService.cs:line 355
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Server.ServiceHooksService.d__68.MoveNext() in d:\v2.0\P1_work\8\s\ServiceHooks\Service\Server\ServiceHooksService.cs:line 2759

I tried regenerating the Webhook URL, but no success. Other events do work, "Build completed" does not.

Any ideas what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rick Potts from Microsoft posted yesterday [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/371075/slack-servicehooks-no-longer-working.html) this:

> The problem is with the TEST feature for a build completed service
>   hooks subscription. It does not impact notification of real build
>   completed event. The problem was introduced a few weeks ago with the
>   most recent deployment. The solution for this problem will be deployed
>   to all accounts over the next week.

Comment: Sadly in my case the real build events also fail.